# Can't get Scrollspy to work on my website

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to use ScrollSpy to highlight active links in my fixed Bootstrap Navbar, but I can't get it to work. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```html
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#topnav" data-offset="50">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> 0008 66 88 50 (alleen voor opdrachtgevers)</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="topnav">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#overmij">OVER MIJ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#beschikbaarheid">BESCHIKBAARHEID</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#werkgebied">WERKGEBIED</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tarieven">TARIEVEN</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="overmij">
        <div class="container homepage">
            <img src="images/myself.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="Test" width=20% height=20%>
            <h2>Over mij</h2>
            <hr>
            <p>Test test test test test test test test test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "can't get it to work"? What happens?

Comment: The links aren't highlighted when I scroll down

Comment: I don't know what your problem is. For me your code works: http://www.bootply.com/6lMreOp3CA Did you include the bootstrap.js? Do you close the `body` tag?

Comment: Thanks Sebsemillia! Because of your question whether I included the bootstrap.js, I found out that I didn't use the right path to it in the <script> tag (stupid!). It's working now.